# DataFormatValue issue in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataformat

How can I format to currency the value of a column in my gridview ?

I tryied the following code, but doesn't work, still unformatted.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDetalhePropostaExpirada" Width="100%" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="dsGridExpira">        
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Valor" DataField="ValorProposta" DataFormatString="{0:c}" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set your **HTMLEncode** to False:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Valor" DataField="ValorProposta" HtmlEncode="False" DataFormatString="{0:c}" />
</Columns>
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx): 
*In versions of ASP.NET earlier than 3.5, you must set the HtmlEncode
property to false in order to format fields that are not string data
types. Otherwise, the field value is converted to a string by the
default conversion method before the format string that is stored in
the DataFormatString property is applied.*

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the DataFormatString="{0:$#,##0.00;($#,##0.00);0}"
and setting the HTMLEncoded = false.